# If $U$ is connected, any two sections $U \to \mathfrak S$ either coincide or have disjoint images (Is my proof correct?)

Tags: complex-analysis, sheaf-theory

I tried proving the following statement by Ahlfors, page 287:

> If $U$ is connected and $\varphi,\psi: U \to \Gamma(U,\mathfrak S)$, then either $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are identical, or the images $\varphi(U)$ and $\psi(U)$ are disjoint. Indeed, the sets with $\varphi - \psi = 0$ and $\varphi- \psi \neq 0$ are both open.

Here $\mathfrak S$ is the sheaf of germs of analytic functions over some open set $D \subseteq \mathbb C$, and $\Gamma(U,\mathfrak S)$ is the set of all sections from an open set $U \subseteq D$.

---

Mainly, what I tried is expanding on the openness of the sets $$A=\{ \zeta \in U: \varphi(\zeta)-\psi(\zeta)=\mathbf{0}_\zeta \} \\
B=\{ \zeta \in U: \varphi(\zeta)-\psi(\zeta) \neq \mathbf{0}_\zeta \} $$

$A$ can be viewed as the inverse image $$(\varphi-\psi)^{-1}[\omega(U)] $$ where $\omega:\zeta \mapsto \mathbf{0}_\zeta$ is the *zero section*. Since it is an open map, and $\varphi-\psi$ is continuous it follows that $A$ is open.

However, proving that $B$ is open turned out to be more problematic for me. I couldn't do it using representation as an inverse image, so I tried the more direct approach: Let $\zeta_0 \in B$ and suppose that in every arbitrarily small disk $\Delta(\zeta_0,r)$ there exists a point $\zeta_r$ such that $(\varphi-\psi)(\zeta_r)=\mathbf{0}_{\zeta_r} \equiv \omega(\zeta_r)$. Thus we may extract a sequence $\{\zeta_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ which tends to $\zeta_0$, such that for all $n$, $(\varphi-\psi)(\zeta_n)=\omega(\zeta_n)$. Since both $\varphi-\psi$ and $\omega$ are continuous, they are sequentially continuous, and taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ yields the contradiction $\varphi(z_0)-\psi(\zeta_0)=\mathbf{0}_{\zeta_0}$. It follows that $B$ is open as well.

Lastly, $U=A \coprod B$, and from connectedness either $U=A$ or $U=B$. In the former $\varphi,\psi$ coincide, and in the latter they have disjoint images (this is because if they share a value, they must share it at the same point).

Is this all correct? If not, please help me correct it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minor point: "$\varphi,\psi: U \to \Gamma(U,\mathfrak S)$" should be either  $\varphi,\psi  \in \Gamma(U,\mathfrak S)$   or $\varphi,\psi: U \to  \mathfrak S $, but not the mix of both notation.

Your proof of the openness of $A$ is correct.

Before discussing the openness of $B$, let's note that Ahlfors placed the quoted statement incorrectly. It comes    *before* he restricts consideration to the sheaf of analytic germs. But for general sheaves the quoted statement is false. 
For example, consider the sheaf of germs of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$. Define $f,g\in C(\mathbb R)$ by  $f(x)\equiv 0$ and $g(x)=  \max(x,0) $. Each continuous functions induce  a section of the sheaf, because for each $x$ it 
 determines a germ at $x$. Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be the  sections induced by $f$ and $g$ respectively. The set 
 $\{\varphi=\psi\}=(-\infty,0)$ is open, but its complement $\{\varphi\ne \psi\}=[0,\infty) $ is not.

Your argument for the openness of $B$ implicitly assumes that the limit of a sequence is unique. But sheaves can be
non-Hausdorff, e.g.,  the sheaf of the germs of continuous functions. Indeed, in the preceding example $\varphi(0)\ne \psi(0)$, 
but both these points are limits of the sequence $\varphi(-1/n)$.

To fix the proof, you should use the fact that you are dealing with analytic germs. For example: let $\zeta\in B$. Pick some function elements $(f,\Omega)$ and $(g,\Omega)$ that determine the germs $\varphi(\zeta)$ and $\psi(\zeta)$,
respectively. Since the zeros of $f-g$ are isolated, by shrinking $\Omega$ we may assume $f\ne g$ in $\Omega\setminus \{\zeta\}$. 
Hence, at each $w\in \Omega$ the germ  $(f-g)_w$ is nonzero. The set of all germs determined by $(f-g,\Omega)$ is an open subset of 
$\mathfrak S$, hence its preimage under $\varphi-\psi$ is an open subset of $U$. This subset contains $\zeta$, and is contained in $B$.

Comment: What about the fact that the sheaf of germs of analytic functions is metrizable as Ahlfors claims? Does it save my proof? Nonetheless yours is more of my type.

Comment: @user1337 Yes, if you know the sheaf is Hausdorff, the proof works. (Though I'd rather not go to the sequential continuity; looking at the preimages of disjoint neighborhoods is enough.) Indeed, most of my proof amounts to showing that the sheaf is Hausdorff: given distinct germs on the same stalk, I find disjoint neighborhoods (the set of  germs determined by $(f,\Omega)$ and the set of germs determined by  $(g,\Omega)$). For germs that are not on the same stalk, the existence of disjoint neighborhoods is clear.